Cannot resolve local hostnames in Ubuntu Server 22.04
I can't resolve local hostnames while remote ones work...
ping unifi
ping: unifi: Temporary failure in name resolution
...
ping google.de
PING google.de (142.250.185.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google.de (142.250.185.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=25.5 ms
64 bytes from google.de (142.250.185.195): icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=26.7 ms
64 bytes from google.de (142.250.185.195): icmp_seq=3 ttl=112 time=130 ms

I have tried:
a) change dns in netplan.yaml (remove 8.8.8.8):
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.12/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2

and then
sudo netplan apply
WARNING:root:Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.

b) removed 8.8.8.8 in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf

to look like this:
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.1.1

then restarted the service
sudo service systemd-resolved restart

to get
resolvectl status

Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub
     DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Link 2 (ens18)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

c) changed resolv.conf's symlink
sudo mv -f /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak

then
sudo ln -sv /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
'/etc/resolv.conf' -> '/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf'

sudo nano /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf looks like this:
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search .

and yes...
d) i have restarted the machine
in the end... nothing has changed, i can ping remote hosts, but no local ones.
The Router at 192.168.1.1 is set
Primary DNS Server 192.168.1.1 (IP of the router)
Secondary DNS Server 8.8.8.8 (google)
Of course i can ping local hosts by their IP.
e) I have added local into my /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.12/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1
        search:
        - local
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2

and i have restarted netplan:
sudo netplan apply
WARNING:root:Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.


still names are not resolveable...

f) i have checked avahi service
sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon

maybe from here we can find something?
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-05-07 17:01:20 UTC; 2h 42min ago
TriggeredBy: ● avahi-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 3008 (avahi-daemon)
     Status: "avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9269)
     Memory: 944.0K
        CPU: 98ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
             ├─3008 "avahi-daemon: running [automator.local]"
             └─3009 "avahi-daemon: chroot helper"

May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Interface ens18.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface ens18.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.12.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: New relevant interface ens18.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.12 on ens18.IPv4.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.12 on ens18.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface ens18.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.12.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Interface ens18.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface ens18.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.12.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: New relevant interface ens18.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 07 19:43:06 automator avahi-daemon[3008]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.12 on ens18.IPv4.


Please edit/update your question with more info regarding your network configuration. What router? What is your DHCP server? What is your local DNS server? What device is associated with the unifi hostname? How is this device getting an IP address? Static or DHCP? But simply put, you’re not defining a search domain in your Netplan config. This search domain has to match what is defined in your DHCP server. If the UniFi device is set statically, then the UniFi host needs to be registered in your DNS server. If DHCP, then that server will have registered the hostname when it issued a lease.

You also need an entry in /etc/hosts file if not using a search domain.  See Manpage for hosts file

I have updated netplan (see edit), no dice. I have posted also avahi output. I am aware that i could put a list of all hosts present into the hosts file but that is like a "last resort". I am also curious why it does not work...
